# RegExp - If first part of search string is found then replace with the full search string value

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

Is there a RegExp to find and replace a value based on the criteria, "if first part of search string is in the target string then replace the part that matches with the search string."

This is a special search and replace because the replacement is also used as the search string.

For example, I have this URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/path/something/more/something/
```

Search for any part of the following and replace with the whole:

```
/path/user/
```

Since, "/path/" is in both the replacement string and the target string the results would be:

```
http://www.domain.com/path/user/something/more/something/
```

NOTE: The search / replacement value can be anything.

I don't know what the replacement and search string is at the time I make a replacement so I can't use something that hard codes the search string. For example, this won't work because the term is hard coded:

```
s.replace(/(\/path\/)/, "$1value/");
```

**Another example:**
Here is the sentence, "Thank you Susan for your order."
Here is the search and replacement, "Susan Summers"
Here is the desired sentence, "Thank you Susan Summers for your order."

**Use Case:**
Lets say you are given 1 million text documents that are letters to customers but when they created the documents they used the customers first name only when they were supposed to use the full name. Now it's your job to find and replace every occurrence of their first name with their full name. You only have their full name to work with not first name.

Just realized this may not work as a RegEx and might require code.

Comment: When you say "Search for any *part* of the following and replace with the whole" - what constitutes a *part*?  Using your example URL along with `/path/user/`, couldn't we say that `/` is a part of the search string which is found in the target string, and so the result could be: `http:/path/user//path/user/www.domain.com/path/user/path/path/user/user...`? So, by "*part*" - do you mean the largest possible part of the search string that matches in the target string?  Or do you mean one or more strings fully encapsulated by parentheses (like `/path/` or `/path/user/`) ?

Comment: First occurance. I've added more examples and a use case.

Comment: Sorry for continued clarification questions. When you say "first occurrence", I would assume that means the shortest possible string in your search string that matches in your target string. In your example, that would be `S` and not ` Susan`. And so, the result would be "Thank you Susan Summersusan for your order...

Comment: What if first name is `Susim` should it still be replaced `"Susan Summers"` since first 3 letters match.

Comment: Good questions. I think it should be up to the first non letter character. So any character that is not a letter. Examples would be "." or " " or "," etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s = 'http://www.domain.com/path/something/more/something/';
r = s.replace(/(\/path\/)/, "$user/");
//=> "http://www.domain.com/path/user/something/more/something/"
```

Comment: Sorry, the search string may or may not be "/path/". The criteria is "if any part of search string is in the target string then replace the part that matches with the search string." I'll update the question.

Comment: Yep. Added a few more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regular expression for this case:

```
var url = 'http://www.domain.com/path/something/more/something/';
url.replace('/path/', '/path/user/');
// => "http://www.domain.com/path/user/something/more/something/"
```

Comment: But it will also replace `/paths` to `/users`

Comment: @anubhava, You're right. I updated the code (appended a trailing `/`). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`split` + `join` alternative :

```
url = url.split('/path/').join('/path/user/');
```

---

Although your requirements are not clear, here is a guess that raises a few extra questions :

```
var sub = '/path/user/';
var parts = sub.match(/[^\/]+/g);
url = url.replace(new RegExp(
    '\\/(' + [parts.join('\\/')].concat(parts).join('|') + ')\\/'
), sub);
```

The resulting regular expression is as follows :

```
/\/(path\/user|path|user)\// // "/path/user/" OR "/path/" OR "/user/"
```

Let's check some urls assuming we live in the best of worlds :

```
'http://domain/'         -> 'http://domain/'
'http://path/user/'      -> 'http://path/user/'
'http://path/'           -> 'http://path/user/'
'http://user/'           -> 'http://path/user/'
```

Now, what do you think about the following ones?

```
'http://path/user'       -> 'http://path/user/user'
'http://user/path/'      -> 'http://path/user/path/'
'http://path/user/path/' -> 'http://path/user/path/'
```

The remaining questions are :

- Is this what you are looking for?
- What to do when there is no trailing slash?
- What to do in the reverse order case?
- What to do with recurrent parts?

Comment: Sorry, I need the search string to be dynamic and based on the replacement value. I updated the question.

Comment: I added a new example and use case. In this case it would be first occurrence since I'm trying to change the path in a URL. PS nice avatar icon.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Thanks :D You said "in this case" but there are 3 cases exposed. Could you clarify each point one by one the same way as I do (`input -> output`)? That would be helpful :)

Comment: In the "...best of both worlds" all results are desired except the last one. Last one should remain as the input. Also, note the new examples in the original post with the first name use case. You have taken into account the condition where the first and last name may also be present.

Comment: Also, in the section, "Now, what do you think about the following ones?" those are all undesired results as you have correctly identified.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Are you actually working with names? If so, are you able to split the full name in a reliable way? Indeed, I guess you have already noticed that, if first and last name are made of 1+ words, there is no way to know where to cut the full name in order to retrieve the individual parts. In this case, you could use a regex like the following which looks for the longest possible strings first (does not handle typos) : `/John Edgar Hoover|John Edgar|John/g`.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts However, it's still like playing Russian roulette :) You'll have to find a recurring pattern shared between all names in order to make the replacement as reliable as it can be. As an example, you could include some of the surrounding characters into the regex : `/Hello (John Edgar Hoover|John Edgar|John)!/`. Or much simpler : `/Hello .*?!/`.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Check this sample : `'Hello John Edgar Hoover!'.replace(/Hello .*?!/, 'Hello JEH!')`.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know if it will work as a RegEx. If they have 1+ name, "Mary Tyler Moore" then there is the problem. If everyone had first name and last name I could split the first name, "Susan Smith" to get "Susan" and then replace with "Susan Smith".

Comment: @1.21gigawatts That's why I've suggested these "longuest possible string" and "surrounding characters" methods. Keep me informed :)

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Replacement based on the longest possible string : `text.replace(/John Edgar|John/g, 'John Edgar Hoover')`. Replacement based on surrounding characters : `'Hello John!'.replace(/Hello .*?!/, 'Hello John Edgar Hoover!')`. Try it into you browser console.

Comment: The example I gave was just an example. The string will not always be "Hello John!" It will be *any text* and *any replace* string.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Too bad. Well, I give up :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the problem correctly. The following replaces any part of of /path/user/ (-> part 1: 'path', part 2: 'user') with the whole /path/user:

```
var url1 = "http://www.domain.com/path/something/more/something/";
var url2 = "http://www.domain.com/user/something/more/something/";
url1.replace(/\/path\/|\/user\//, '/path/user/');
url2.replace(/\/path\/|\/user\//, '/path/user/');
```

results in:

```
http://www.domain.com/path/user/something/more/something/
http://www.domain.com/path/user/something/more/something/
```

I hope this is what you need, otherwise, please add another example.

**EDIT:**

Here is the regex in action: http://regex101.com/r/jL6tK6